# Is this pulp program ok?

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I am using pulp,

I wonder if my python pulp code is possible and won't break the linear laws (The Proportionality and Additivity Assumptions).

I have a factory that manufactures wooden toys.
I have to build fire trucks (3dollars), helicopters(2 dollars) and ambulances(4 dollars) out of wood.
2 employees, who work 1 hour, 2 hours, 3 hours for respective objects for a maximum of 100 hours / week.
****** For one fire truck produced, I need to produce 2 ambulances. *****

Please have a look at this constraint :

**prob + = x1 * 2 == x2**

Can somebody tell me if it breaks the The Proportionality and Additivity Assumptions? looks like it is working correctly, but I can't really tell..

```
import pulp
from pulp import *
 
# We declare the variables
x1 = LpVariable ("x1", 0, 1000)
x2 = LpVariable ("x2", 0, 1000)
x3 = LpVariable ("x3", 0, 1000)


# WE say it's a maximization problem, because we want to maximize our profits.
prob = LpProblem ("problem", LpMaximize)


# We define the economic function to be maximized
prob + = 3 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 4 * x3
 
# Then, we define the constraints.

# Max working hours
prob + = 1 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 3 * x3 <= 100

# We oblige Pulp that for 1 truck produced (x1) it must produce 2 helicopters (x2)
# In other words, we always produce 2 * more trucks than helicopters
# In the result, we see that forcing a multiple works
prob + = x1 * 110 == x2

 
# solve the problem
prob.solve ()
 
# We print the results

print ("Status:", LpStatus [prob.status])
for v in prob.variables ():
    print (v.name, "=", v.varValue)

"" "After Postsolve, objective 200, infeasibilities - dual 0 (0), primal 0 (0)
Optimal objective 200 - 1 iterations time 0.012, Presolve 0.00
Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds): 0.05 (Wallclock seconds): 0.05

Status: Optimal
x1 = 20.0
x2 = 40.0
x3 = 0.0
```

Comment: `2*x1 = x2 <-> 2*x1 - x2 = 0`. Now compare this with [Linear equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation). This is a perfectly normal constraint in (MI)LPs. Equalities like that only hurt when doing more general opt, like quadratically constrained things. (imho pulp's domain-specific language will recognize problems like `x2^2` and co.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Ok, I am trying to understand